# How would I make this bean in JavaConfig, I dont want to use XML with Spring anymore

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a project and I need to set the following bean and property but I dont want to do it in XML.. I want to do it in JavaCofig style.. Can someone please show me how I would do this in javaconfig stlye

```
<!-- Spring Configuration needed to avoid URI using dots to be truncated -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@Bean public DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping(){
        DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping bean = new DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping();
        bean.setUseDefaultSuffixPattern(false);
        return bean;
    }
```

You can see my sample spring MVC app using code config here https://github.com/robhinds/spring-code-configuration-webapp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tmm/web/configuration/WebMvcConfiguration.java

Comment: rhinds answer is correct. Just to add to this, the transformation between xml and java config is very straight forward. The class attribute in <bean> is the type of object you want to create so create an instance of that class. The <property> elements are fields on that object that you need to set. The name attribute is the name of the field so that becomes the setter and the value or ref attribute is what should be passed into the setter.